# How do i add an play again option to this java code?

Tags: java

[image: the notepad++ file screenshot]

is there a way to declare a char early on but use it only later, because when i try to declare it as 0 early on then it will just cause an error because the answer of while is supposed to be 'Y'.  i could  get it to loop and play again by asking the question before playing but I only  want it to ask the option to play again at the end of the game. would appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to get this to work, thank you.

```
public class soodsami_a3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sam = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Random number generator
        int Randomizer = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

        while (playagain == 'y') {
            System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100");
            System.out.println("What is it?");
            System.out.print("Guess:  ");
            int Useranswer = sam.nextInt();
            
            while (Useranswer != Randomizer) {
                if (Useranswer < Randomizer) {
                    System.out.println("Too low.");
                    System.out.print("Guess:  ");
                    Useranswer = sam.nextInt();
                } else if (Useranswer > Randomizer) {
                    System.out.println("Too high.");
                    System.out.print("Guess:  ");
                    Useranswer = sam.nextInt();
                }
            
                if (Useranswer == Randomizer) {
                    System.out.println("You got it!");
                }
            
                System.out.print("would you like to play again (Y/N) ");
                char playagain = sam.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the code to the question please. not as an image.

Comment: sorry new to all of this stuff so please ignore the way it looks

Comment: @SamikSood https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html check out naming conventions when you have the time..

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ...
    char playagain = 'y';

    while (playagain == 'y') {
        // ...
        playagain = scan.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    }

    System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be a better practice to have `playagain` as a `boolean` and have it set to `false` on initialization. Then use a `do-while` cycle, to have the condition evaluated at the end of the cycle, so that it runs at least once

```
boolean playAgain = false;
do {
    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100");
    //..other code..
    playAgain = sam.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'Y';
} while (playAgain);
```